# Magento 2 Update mass Product description using $mysqli->real_escape_string() using core php root script

Tags: database, magento2.4.1, php-7.4, product-description, webroot

After migrating all data from Magento 1.9 aproximat 800 product have static image urls in descriptin.
`{{skin url="images/seringue.gif"}}`

So I have created one root script to update all product descriptions programmatically...

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('memory_limit', '5G');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

include 'app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/product_update_description.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('Update Product Description'); // Simple Text Log
$logger->info('ID'); // Simple Text Log
$allProductIds = [7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15];
foreach ($allProductIds as $productId){
    $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
    $product->load($productId);
    $description = str_replace('{{skin url="images/seringue.gif"}}','{{media url=&quot;wysiwyg/seringue.gif&quot;}}',$product->getDescription());
    $product->setDescription($description);
    $logger->info($product->getId().','.$product->getSku()); // Simple Text Log
    $product->save();
}

$resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$connection = $resource->getConnection();

$selectSql = "SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_entity_text` WHERE `value` LIKE '%{{skin url=\"images/seringue.gif\"}}%' AND value_id='37531'";
$result = $connection->fetchAll($selectSql);
$resource->closeConnection();
foreach ($result as $product) {
//print_r($product['value']);
    $logger->info($product['entity_id']);
    $description = str_replace('{{skin url="images/seringue.gif"}}','{{media url=&quot;wysiwyg/seringue.gif&quot;}}',$product['value']);
   $sql = "UPDATE `catalog_product_entity_text` SET `value` = '".$description."' WHERE `value_id` = '".$product['value_id']."';";
    $connection->query($sql);
}
```

The full script runs without success, in the database, nothing is changed.

Answer (score 0):

when I have manually updated the description in the database and compare both queries then I found that this is an issue of HTML data are encrypted and in MySQL query that was run in PHPMyAdmin and this is an issue in so I have used the `mysql_real_escape_string`  function but the letter I found that this function is deprecated in PHP 5 and removed from php 7 :D.

```
$sql = "UPDATE `catalog_product_entity_text` SET `value` = '".mysql_real_escape_string ($description)."' WHERE `value_id` = '".$product['value_id']."';";
```

So I have run bellow script and all product description are updated successfully.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('memory_limit', '5G');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$url='localhost:3306';
$username='magento2_db';
$password='pass';
$db = "mage_v241";

$conn=mysqli_connect($url,$username,$password,$db);

if(!$conn){
    die('Could not Connect My Sql:' .mysql_error());
}

$mysqli = new mysqli($url,$username,$password,$db);

if ($mysqli -> connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $mysqli -> connect_error;
    exit();
}

$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_entity_text` WHERE `value` LIKE '%{{skin url=\"images/seringue.gif\"}}%'");
echo "entity id";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<br>";
    echo $row['entity_id'];
    $description = str_replace('{{skin url="images/seringue.gif"}}','{{media url=&quot;wysiwyg/seringue.gif&quot;}}',$row['value']);
    $description = $mysqli -> real_escape_string($description);
    $sql = "UPDATE `catalog_product_entity_text` SET `value` = '".$description."' WHERE `value_id` = '".$row['value_id']."';";
    mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
}
?>
```

Thank you.